# Load all files to Service Workers from folders

Tags: service, service-worker

I am trying to use Service Workers for my website but I don´t have experience with this technology. Is it possible to add whole folder (e.g. folder with all .js´s / .css´s) to `sw.js` instead of adding each file separately like

```
this.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
event.waitUntil(
  caches.open('v1').then(function (cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/sw-test/',
        '/sw-test/library/4.0/4.0/init.js',
        '/sw-test/library/4.0/4.0/esri/css/main.css',
        '/sw-test/library/4.0/4.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css',
        '/sw-test/library/4.0/4.0/',
        '/sw-test/index.html',
         '/sw-test/app.js',
         '/sw-test/styl.css',
         '/sw-test/bootstrap.css',
         '/sw-test/close.png'
      ]);
  })
);
```

...?